# Android Studio 2.3 not showing exception stacktrace

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-2.3

I have updated Android Studio from 2.2 to 2.3, and now when any exception is thrown it does not appear in the "Run" section at all.

What I get only is a message that "Application terminated."

Even when I throw an exception deliberately, stacktrace is not showing...

[image]

Comment: Hmmm I always used the "Android Monitor", not "Run". Have you looked there? - on right end of the toolbar of android monitor there are your filters. Take care that you monitor current application only.

Comment: They probably removed it from there. Try the android monitor and make sure you have the right package selected over there

Comment: Logcat does not show up in Run as @Grisgram has just said, check Android Monitor and click the logcat tab

Comment: Thanks everybody, I'll use now "Android Monitor"...they probably removed it from there

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem ...Go to android monitor tab set the value of the menu in the middle to verbose....set the value of the right menu to show only selected application...and it works..now i can see what exactly causes my application to crush ..hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Try to disconnect your device, close Android studio and make sure every instance of adb closes as well (either by closing it in your task manager or by rebooting your computer).
It should be back when you open Android studio and connect your device again.

Comment: this is good if everything seems to be playing up - you should kill your whole adb and just restart it

Answer (score 0):

I have been facing this problem for the last 5 days and searched a lot in google to see what could have been the problem but found no useful solution.

**At last I just changed my Android Emulator and that did the work.

I was using Nox app player and then installed Genymotion, and that did the trick. If you are already using Genymotion then my suggestion would be, try uninstalling it and reinstall or you could try some other emulator to see if that works for you.

Answer (score 0):

A solution could be:

1- Close the error message (when it appears in your phone)

2- Open Logcat window and make sure:

* The correct device and the correct application are selected

* In the third field, select: "Error"

* In the last field, select: "No filters"

3- Press "Restart" in Logcat window

Excuse me for my English!